# Creating a model instance of a user based on an open session

Tags: php, design-patterns, dao, factory-pattern

I'm following the Data Access Object pattern, along with Factory (edit: sorry if I'm doing noob mistakes).

#### To log in a User, I currently do:

```
$user_dao = UserDaoFactory::getUserDaoFactory()->getUserDao();
$user = $user_dao->create($_POST['email'], $_POST['password']);
if ($user_dao->authenticate($user))
{
    $user_dao->login($user); // sets $_SESSION['id']
}
```

My question is for consequent pages. Given that the user is in effect logged in, how should I go about creating and accessing an instance of their User model?

To get an instance of the logged in user, should I do something like the following?

#### To continue the session on the next page, should I try the following?

```
$user_dao = UserDaoFactory::getUserDaoFactory()->getUserDao();
$user = $user_dao->userFromSession($_SESSION['id']);
if ($user->isLoggedIn()) {
    // success
}
```

I would have to do this every place I need to know something about the currently logged in user.

#### Or try this other approach?

Or should I be abstracting the "give me an instance of the logged in user model" to something like a user Factory?

For example, storing an instance of the logged in User in a `private static` property of a User class?

```
class User {
    /* ... */
    private static $_logged_in_user;
    
    public static function setUserLoggedIn(User $user)
    {
        self::$_logged_in_user = $user;
    }
    
    public static function getLoggedInUser() {
        if (!self::$_logged_in_user)
    {
        self::$_logged_in_user = new self;
    }
    return self::$_logged_in_user;
    }
    /* ... */
}
$user = User::getLoggedInUser();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a separate class for authorization purpose, logging in method should not belong to user model. Kohana framework implements this quite well - check out this link just to get a basic idea: http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Auth.

Comment: I'm just curious, why shouldn't the user model (or user data access object) deal with authentication? It seems part of what I consider to be "manipulate the user object".

Answer (score 0):

I would encapsulate that into a service layer, use that service-layer only and solve it once in there. Then you can change it later on w/o changing your whole application.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you mean accessing a service layer in this context?

Comment: Just a layer around your data models. So a new User object has a simpler interface and inside the new User object you deal with the details how you would like to implement things. Within your application code you only access the new User object, so you layered the data models and the session logic away from it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the user DAO you need only once: when you authenticate user and get his personal info (such as name or role). After that you can store this data in session and during every new request restore it foк you purposes.

As for `isLogged()` function, I prefer to use some logic incapsulated in class User, instead of saving once more instance of class User itself (such as `private static $_logged_in_user;`
 in your example)

So, one instance of User per request is my choise.